# Checking for conditional convergence when the Dirichlet's test is not applicable

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Problem**

How to check for conditional convergence if the Dirichlet's /Abel test is not applicable.

**Statement for Dirichlet's test**

> Let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $a<sub>n</sub> be a series of complex terms whose partial sum form a bounded sequence . Let {b<sub>n</sub>} be a decreasing sequence which converge to 0 . Then the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $a<sub>n</sub> b<sub>n</sub> converges.

**Statement for Abel's test**

> Let $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $a<sub>n</sub> be a convergent series of complex terms and let {b<sub>n</sub>} be a monotonic convergent sequence of real terms . Then  $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} $a<sub>n</sub> b<sub>n</sub> converges.

For example $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n sin( \frac{1}{\log(n)} )$ .

As far as i can tell this is not monotonic . How to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any new test for the series you are interested in. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} {a_n}$  converges if $a_n$ decreases to $0$. This theorem applies when $a_n=\sin (\frac 1 {\log n})$ [$\sin x$ is increasing on $[0,\frac {\pi} 2]$].